# Firebase Cloud Function to fetch documentd

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am making an ios app where I use the cloud functions to do all the back-end tasks of the app.

But I had a question...

It's a good idea and it would benefit me if I implement some cloud function that fetch documents, instead of doing it directly from the app.

It would just be to get the data and do a bit of logic, to return the snapshot data to the user.

Something like this:

```
exports.getLikedComments = functions.https.onCall(async (data, {auth}) => {
  const uid = auth?.uid;
  if (uid == null) return {alert: "access-denied"};

  try {
    const id = data.post_id;

    return await db.collection("posts").doc(id).collection("liked-comments").doc(uid).get();
  } catch (err) {
    functions.logger.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
});
```

Comment: See https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c

Comment: Just to add to the above link as well as @frankvanpuffelen answer, there *will* be a cost difference as *none* of the data returned from that http request will be cached whereas if it was done with the SDK, it would be, therefore reducing costs as some of the data will exist locally.

Comment: Good point Jay! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the code you shared there is very little difference between running this code in Cloud Functions or running the equivalent code in your app itself with the security rules set to [allow every authenticated user read access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#all_authenticated_users).

Whether that is a good idea, depends largely on your definition of a good idea. Since that is subjective, it is not something we can objectively answer here on Stack Overflow. You (being new to serverless) may find it weird to access data directly from your app, while I (a BaaS veteran) wonder why on earth you'd use a Cloud Function like that. Neither of those viewpoints is pertinently wrong, they're just subjective - based on our personal experiences.